# Какие методы позиционирования используются в приложениях геолокации?

Tags: методы, геолокация, позиционирование

Какие методы позиционирования используются в приложениях геолокации?

Comment: В самих приложениях - никакие. Они лишь используют API операционной системы. А уже сама ОС использует GPS или базу сотовых вышек.

Comment: я имею ввиду методы а не технологии (например Rssi fingerprint ,ToA).например  ОС  может  при wi fi позицианировании использовать Rssi fingerprint . и вообше какие методы могут использоваться?